# how to use a string that contain ' in SQL "IN" clause

Tags: sql, select

i have a string value like 'Apple's'. i want to use this string in SQL "IN" clause like below query

```
select * from tbl_fruit where nm_fruit IN(''Apple's'','Orange');
```

how i can get the above query work correctly ?

Many Thanks,
Awais Afzal.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

double the single quotes,

```
select * from tbl_fruit where nm_fruit IN ('Apple''s', 'Orange')
```

but if you do it on the application level, make sure you parameterized the query `:)`

Comment: If you parameterize the query, you don't have to quote the quotes, at least not if you do it with Coldfusion.  I assume it's the same for .net, php, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have found SQL correctly interprets the ASCII single-closed-quote (ALT 0146) as an apostrophe in searches while the "IN" treats it like any other character. Now I can search for 'Matt's Macintosh' using Matt(ASCII character 0146)s Macintosh" without messing up my list or the search.